# HTML Canvas draws all the objects with the same color, though their color attributes are different

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

//set up

`var a_canvas = document.getElementById("a");
var context = a_canvas.getContext("2d");`

//draw the graph

```
    function drawGraph(){
    for(i in data.nodes)
    {
            console.log(data.nodes[i].color);

            context.fillStyle = data.nodes[i].color;
            context.rect(data.nodes[i].x,data.nodes[i].y,data.nodes[i].size,data.nodes[i].size);
            context.fill();

    }
}
```

The console log:

`yellow
yellow
blue`

But all rectanges are drawed with blue color.

What should I do, to draw fill all rectangles with its given color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `context.fill` fills whatever was drawn in the current path. And you never reset, so you will always fill all rects with the last color in your list.

Use `context.beginPath()` before you set `fillStyle`, and subsequent fills will only affect the current path.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6hjpzboL/)